# How to get the scroll direction of a NestedScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get the scroll direction (Up/Down) of a NestedScrollView so one of my widgets can react accordingly.

I've already used the NotificationListener widget and tried to print the axisDirection that it returns but it only returns "down" when I scroll in both directions. apparently that's the way it supposed to behave but still, it doesn't look like there's any way in Flutter to know how to get the scroll direction.
Is there any way to get the scroll direction whether be it as an AxisDirection or a bool ?.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 22, 22, 22),
          body: NotificationListener<ScrollStartNotification>(
            onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {


              print("scrollInfo up ===== ${scrollInfo.metrics.axisDirection}");


            },
            child: NotificationListener<ScrollStartNotification>(
              onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
                if (scrollInfo.metrics.axisDirection == AxisDirection.down) {
                  print(
                      "scrollViewColtroller down == ${scrollViewColtroller.position.axisDirection}");
                }
              },
              child: NestedScrollView(
                controller: scrollViewColtroller,
                headerSliverBuilder:
                    (BuildContext context, bool boxIsScrolled) {
                  return <Widget>[
                    SliverAppBar(
                      floating: true,
                      snap: true,
                      pinned: false,
                      elevation: 10,
                    )
                  ];
                },
                body: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                        _feedPosts(context)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is what it prints.

```dart
scrollViewColtroller up ===== AxisDirection.down
scrollInfo up == AxisDirection.down
scrollViewColtroller up ===== AxisDirection.down
scrollInfo up == AxisDirection.down
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the Direction with the help of - `scrollViewColtroller.position`

First add - `import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';`

Code:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //  backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 22, 22, 22),
      body: NotificationListener<ScrollUpdateNotification>(
        onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
          if (scrollViewColtroller.position.userScrollDirection ==
              ScrollDirection.reverse) {
            print('User is going down');
            setState(() {
              message = 'going down';
            });
          } else {
            if (scrollViewColtroller.position.userScrollDirection ==
                ScrollDirection.forward) {
              print('User is going up');
              setState(() {
                message = 'going up';
              });
            }
          }
        },
        child: NestedScrollView(
          controller: scrollViewColtroller,
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool boxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                floating: true,
                snap: true,
                pinned: false,
                elevation: 10,
              )
            ];
          },
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 150.0,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Text(
                      message,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                  children: List.generate(100, (i) {
                    return Text(i.toString());
                  }).toList(),
                ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: That did it for me, thank you so much, your work is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something changed that this is not working anymore.

Comment: Where are you getting the `scrollViewController` from?

Comment: @eja initialize a new ScrollController() like this;

final ScrollController scrollViewController;

override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    scrollViewController = ScrollController();
  }

 void dispose() {
   scrollViewController.dispose();
   super.dispose();
}

Answer (score 8):

[`AxisDirection`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/AxisDirection-class.html) isn't used to detect scrolling direction, it is used to return the [`Scrollable`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Scrollable-class.html) structure, in your case the `NestedScrollView` has `scrollDirection = Axis.Vertical` by default, which makes its beginning at top and its `AxisDirection = AxisDirection.down`. So when you tried to scroll up and down you received the same result because list structure doesn't change by scrolling events.

To achieve what you want you can compare the current position to the default one (`0.0`), if the `ScrollNotification.metrics.pixels` greater than previous position, then the list is scrolling up (or left in case of horizontal ones), or down if it is less.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final appTitle = 'Scroll Direction Detection';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>{

  double position = 0.0 ;

  double sensitivityFactor = 20.0 ;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
            onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
              if(scrollInfo.metrics.pixels - position >= sensitivityFactor){
                print('Axis Scroll Direction : Up');
                position = scrollInfo.metrics.pixels ;
              }
              if(position - scrollInfo.metrics.pixels  >= sensitivityFactor){
                print('Axis Scroll Direction : Down');
                position = scrollInfo.metrics.pixels ;
              }

            },
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('$index'),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I followed this solution but still, there seems to be a confusion. This is what is printed when I scroll up or down:

I/flutter (11861): Current Position is : 233.10196120502707
I/flutter (11861): Axis Scroll Direction : Down
I/flutter (11861): Current Position is : 56.0
I/flutter (11861): Axis Scroll Direction : Up
I/flutter (11861): Current Position is : 1276.1869769538555
I/flutter (11861): Axis Scroll Direction : Down
I/flutter (11861): Current Position is : 56.0
I/flutter (11861): Axis Scroll Direction : Up

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with this, I just added them to verify my results.

Comment: And I'm really grateful for your effort.. my comment was meant to show you that I have yet to reach the desired result of knowing exactly whether I'm scrolling up or down.. like I've mentioned before, the log shows me that I'm scrolling both up and down, and that seems to not be what I'm looking for, what I need is to get the precise result for whether I'm scrolling up or down. It will help a lot for a widget that i have to behave in the correct way when i'm scrolling up or down. And thank you for your effort.

Comment: @johnharis thanks pal ! look at first I noticed this and thought there was something wrong on the logic, but there isn't (to the best of my knowledge). The cause of this behavior is due to our finger movement, if you're scrolling down and your finger moved just one pixel up it will print up. You can fix this by triggering only if the difference is larger than some threshold (say 20 pixels).

Comment: I've tried to modify the code (print('Axis Scroll Direction : ${scrollInfo.metrics.pixels > position + 10 ? 'down' : 'up'}');).

But still the same issue. Looks like it will take a lot of hit and miss to get to the desired result ;)

Comment: @johnharis I fixed the issue, turned out the logic wasn't tight, hope it helps.

Comment: Still the same thing.. once you scroll down a little it prints (Up) but after a few scroll it prints (Up / Down).